# Phonegap app not scrolling in some Android devices

Tags: android, cordova, scroll, height

I have developed an Android app with phonegap and the content's height is bigger than the screen height. This is not a problem in most of the devices, but in some of them the app will not scroll all the way down, so I cannot see the lowest part of the app.

I edit to say that when the orientation is changed twice, and the screen is taken back to the original position, the whole height appears and the app works correctly.

Any suggestions about what the issue could be?

P.S. I do not mind providing code, but as I have no idea where the issue stands I do not know what I should show, and I do not want to drive you crazy showing code that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on some devices and doesn't work on some, it probably be issue with the phonegap build. I have had the same problem before and it is really a nightmare. Nevertheless, may I have a look at your code, in fact, your xml?

Cheers,

Comment: which xml? It is true that I am using an old build of phonegap, I will try with the newest one and let you know.

Comment: Ok, with the latest version the issue was not solved (the error does not happen in my phone and I was waiting for my friend to test it). Which xml file do you want me to show to you?

Comment: Well, if it is possible, I wanna have a look at the xml file which contains the main content that displayed in the wrong way. Cheers,

Comment: I do that using html and javascript.

Comment: May I have a chance to look into this html file?